# regular expression to find certain bases in a sequence

Tags: python, fasta

In my code, what I'm trying to do is clean up a FastA file by only including the letters A,C,T,G,N, and U in the output string. I'm trying to do this through a regular expression, which looks like this:

```
newFastA = (re.findall(r'A,T,G,C,U,N',self.fastAsequence)) #trying to extract all of the listed bases from my fastAsequence.
        print (newFastA)
```

However, I am not getting all the occurences of the bases in order. I think the format of my regular expression is incorrect, so if you could let me know what mistake I've made, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a character set.

`re.findall(r"[ATGCUN]", self.fastAsequence)`

Your code looks for a LITERAL `"A,T,G,C,U,N"`, and outputs all occurrences of that. Character sets in regex allow for a search of the type: "Any of the following: `A`,`T`,`G`,`C`,`U`,`N`" rather than "The following: `A,T,G,C,U,N` "

Comment: @user3504701 what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: just to make sure: so that will get me any occurence of those bases, in the order they were found in the string

Comment: @user3504701 it certainly should! I don't know what your input looks like, but it seems so. You can do `''.join(re.findall( ... ) )` if you'd rather have them as a string

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid regex entirely.  You can use `str.translate` to remove the characters you don't want.

```
from string import ascii_letters

removechars = ''.join(set(ascii_letters) - set('ACTGNU'))

newFastA = self.fastAsequence.translate(None, removechars)
```

demo:

```
dna = 'ACTAGAGAUACCACG this will be removed GNUGNUGNU'

dna.translate(None, removechars)
Out[6]: 'ACTAGAGAUACCACG     GNUGNUGNU'
```

If you want to remove whitespace too, you can toss `string.whitespace` into `removechars`.

Sidenote, the above only works in python 2, in python 3 there's an additional step:

```
from string import ascii_letters, punctuation, whitespace

#showing how to remove whitespace and punctuation too in this example
removechars = ''.join(set(ascii_letters + punctuation + whitespace) - set('ACTGNU'))

trans = str.maketrans('', '', removechars)

dna.translate(trans)
Out[11]: 'ACTAGAGAUACCACGGNUGNUGNU'
```

Comment: As answer to your sidenote: because it was merged into `str.maketrans`. Now you do `transtable = str.maketrans("", "", removechars); newFastA = self.fastAsequence.translate(transtable)`

Comment: +1 for recommending str.translate ... careful though as your exclude set has to be comprehensive (eg he probably doesnt want the spaces either and it may have punctuation)

Comment: @AdamSmith thanks, I knew there was a way but didn't remember the syntax off the top of my head (it's *way* less intuitive IMO, but I digress)

Comment: I prefer the python3 way. First of all it moved `string.maketrans` to `str.maketrans`, and second of all it made it so the entire translation procedure can be described by a single mapping object instead of two (or three!) arguments sent to `str.translate`.

Comment: It can be made cross-platform by doing `mapping = {ch:None for ch in set(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.whitespace)-set("ACTGNU")}; try: table = str.maketrans(mapping) except AttributeError: string.maketrans(mapping); newFastA = self.fastAsequence.translate(table)`

Comment: Thanks... I haven't thought of using translate

Answer (score 2):

```
print re.sub("[^ACTGNU]","",fastA_string)
```

to go with the million other answers youll get

or without re

```
print "".join(filter(lambda character:character in set("ACTGUN"),fastA_string)
```

Comment: This is probably better than OP's (and my) solution.